# Why is my sapper backend code executed in my browser?

Tags: javascript, axios, svelte, sapper

So, I'm trying to make some calls to a dockerized api from my sapper server using awios and pass the result to the browser. My calls are provided by a "call.js" file.

My "index.svelte" looks like this :

```
<script context="module">
  import * as calls from "./../../utils/calls.js";

  export async function preload({ params, query }) {
    try{
      
    let response = await calls.getStripePub();
    return { api_key: response.data.key };

    }catch(e){
      console.log(e, "error")
      this.error(500, "Oops, unexpected error there");
      
    }
  }
</script>

<script>
  import Payplace from "./../../components/payplace/Payplace.svelte";

  export let api_key;
</script>

<Payplace {api_key} />
```

And my calls.js is :

```
import axios from "axios";

let backend = process.env.IP_BACK
let api_key = `${process.env.API_KEY_NAME}=${process.env.API_KEY}`

export async function getStripePub(){
    console.log(`http://${backend}/stripe/getkeypub/?${api_key}`);
    return await axios.get(`http://${backend}/stripe/getkeypub/?${api_key}`);
}
```

The code works in server side, but it's also executed in my browser, which displays

```
process is not defined
```

Also, the index.js file downloaded by my browser contains

```
let backend = process.env.IP_BACK;
let api_key = `${process.env.API_KEY_NAME}=${process.env.API_KEY}`;

async function getStripePub(){
    console.log(`http://${backend}/stripe/getkeypub/?${api_key}`);
    return await axios$1.get(`http://${backend}/stripe/getkeypub/?${api_key}`);
}
```

Why is my code executed by my browser while it's in the "context='module'" script tag?

Answer (score 2):

Well, your code is in the browser because the `<script context="module">` runs before the component is created [both on the server and on the client](https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#this_fetch). Also, there shouldn't be any environment variables, as they can be read:

> should not reference any API keys or secrets, which will be exposed to
> the client

So I guess you could either try [Server Routes](https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#Server_routes) or use the [onMount](https://svelte.dev/docs#onMount) function, which only runs on the client.